# R: Change default jpeg() export quality via console

Tags: r

how can I change the default jpeg() export quality via console in R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"?

Here is an example: `jpeg('../data/all/graphic1.jpg', quality=100)`

But I don't want to change all separate jpeg() command...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new function that over-rides the default function with a version such as:

```
jpeg <- function(filename, quality=100, ...) grDevices::jpeg(filename, quality, ...)
```

This would work for most common situations where the `jpeg` function is used (say in a user script), but may not work correctly when the `jpeg` function is being called from within functions in other packages.

Comment: Thanks, so I cant change this via a global setting?!?

Comment: @B.Rentrug I don't think so. From the help file and source code it looks like the default argument is hard coded as 75. Compare for example to the argument `antialias` which pulls in a global option `windows.options()$bitmap.aa.win`.